# Tortoise SVN does not show "add" for new directory - why?

Tags: tortoisesvn

On an existing project, with an existing repository i added a new directory.
"add" means i did create the new directory with windows. Tortoise does not yet know about it.  I want to "add" it for Tortoise as well, so i can do a checkin later.

The tortoisesvn doc says 4.11 Adding New Files and Directories :
*If you created new files and/or directories during your development process then you need to add them to source control too. Select the file(s) and/or directory and use TortoiseSVN → Add.*

However the "add" entry does not appear in the popup.
All i see in the popup is "Repo-Browser" | "Export" |  "Create Repository here" | "Import" | "Settings" | "Help" | "About".

No "Add". 
What extra steps do i have to do to add a new directory ?

======================================================

Using Vishals infos my final summary is:

**How to add a directory to tortoise (the full story)**

1) move directory elsewhere, like   /stuff_tmp
This is a security copy. Make sure you have it.

2) in parentdirectory rightmouse to get menu
    -> select SVN Checkout

3)a) change "URL of repository" to point to your repository.

3)b) change checkout directory, to add path
C/users/admin/documents/src/stuff
Tortoise will prefill the path, check with care so you do not
accidentially add to a different place.

3)c) checkout depth **"only this item"**
This is the fun part. Usually a checkout will really checkout.
Here it creates a directory and makes it known to svn.
Tortoise now created "src/stuff" and there is a green checkmark in front of
the directory.

4) The tortoise "add" menu will now be available on toplevel directory /stuff.
But this will not really work (will fail later for checkin).
Add subdirectories manually.

5.1) create /stuff/branches and /stuff/trunk manually (not via tortoise)

5.2) go to /stuff and tortoise "add" branches and trunk

5.3) you would think that you can checkin them - wrong. **Doesnt work.**

5.4) first do tortoise **"update".**

5.5) now you can do tortoise "checkin".

5.6) you now have subdirs branches and trunk. You can see the green checkmark 
in front of the directories, so tortoisesvn really accepts them now.

6) copy your "real" files to inside /trunk

6.1) tortoise "add" them.

6.2) tortoise "checkin" them.  **Done !!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Repository must present where you want to add new  directory.

**Follow steps:**

1. Select  and copy URL where you want to create new directory.
2. Select checkout option in Windows tortoise.
3. Select svn up.
4. Create new directory then right click and add. When you see plus sign on directory it means directory added successfully.
5. svn commit.